# Use Picture In C# WinForms Or Don't Use?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

When I Use Picture (Every Picture) In WinForms in C#.net,My Application is Very Slow.

What Is Solution?

**Edit::**

I Use Picture From Resource into Background of Form.

Comment: Are you resizing your pictures to the minimum size needed for the application? In what way are you "using" pictures?

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to help you.  Are you using a picture box?  Is the image loading the the file system or a resource?  Maybe some example code would be helpful.

Comment: @ James
Yes
Always.............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't likely that a BackgroundImage slows down your form dramatically.  At least on a modern machine.  However, it *does* become a lot more noticeable that your form was slow to begin with.  The time taken to render the controls is a lot more visible, especially when the background image is dark.  The effect is called "flicker", albeit that it isn't the traditional source of flicker.

My post in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls) shows a few cures for it.