# Problem in Drag And Move Forms in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, graphics

I Write a Windows Application By C Sharp.
I Use a Picture in Background of my Form (MainForm) And I Use Many Picture in Buttons in This Form,And also I Use Some Panel And Label with Transparent Background Color.
My Forms,Panels And Buttons has flicker. I solve this problem by a method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls).

But Still when other Forms Start over this Form,my Forms hangs when I Drag and Move my Forms over this Form.How can I Solve this Problem to Move And Drags my Forms easily And Speed?

**Edit::**

My Forms Load Data From Access 2007 DataBase file.I Use Datasets,DataGridViews And Other Components to Load And show Data in My Forms.

Comment: Which method from the other question are you using?

Comment: @MusiGenesis :----> Hans Passant

Comment: As I understand, flickering is not a problem; but Form *hang*-ing is, right? Sounds like you have something inside your form thats eating up the form, probably in `OnPaint` on `OnSize`, just thinking! Can you share some code?

Comment: @KMan : No Problem,I Can....But Please See Edit Section of My Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made it less obvious that your form paints very slowly by using the techniques shown in my answer.  The tricks don't speed it up, they merely make the ugliness less visible.  But they fall flat when you have to paint your form from scratch, which happens when you move another window across it.  The painting cannot keep up with the barrage of paint requests that are generated each time the overlapping form moves by one or more pixels.

An instant fix is to upgrade your operating system to Vista or Windows 7, windows don't overlap anymore with Aero enabled.

Comment: Thank you.But I want Run this Program in Windows Xp.Not Solution Exist for this Problem?

Comment: Does it really matter what you want to run?  What your customer runs ought to count.  Surely they are not using a 9 year old operating system?