# flickering in dot plot on windows 7 aero theme

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, windows-7

We ported win-form application legacy code developed in c# .net framework 1.1 to c# .net 3.5.

There is functionality for drawing dot plot and apply different shapes(polygon,square etc.) on dots in plot.
You can change size of applied shape by dragging using mouse what happening is when dragging shape some part get invisible till we drop to new point and also draws very slow speed.

> you can call it as flickering .
>
> this functionality works fine in windows xp, in windows 7 works fine
>   with basic and classic theme
>
> it flickers only when aero theme is applied in windows 7

i have tried 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/aaed00ce-4bc9-424e-8c05-c30213171c2c
and 
[Flickering in a Windows Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286373/flickering-in-a-windows-forms-app)

none of them helped.

after time stamping execution time i found that

```
 for (int i=0; i < arraypnts.Length - 1; i++) {
           g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, arraypnts[i], arraypnts[i+1]);
         }

         // draw the last line
         g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, arraypnts[0], arraypnts[arraypnts.Length-1]);
```

takes hell lot of time when aero theme applied compared to basic theme applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a workaround for the flickering problem. Just disable the desktop composition — you can do it either at application level or OS level.

For application level, go to exe file -> right click -> compatibility-> check disable desktop composition.

Foror OS level (and better visual appearance), start->right click
computer -> properties -> Advance system settings -> Advance tab ->
performance settings -> visual effects->custom-> uncheck  Enable
desktop composition.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem long time ago and after a while finally found the solution by redrawing components only when setting the Object visibility to false first.

```
Object.Visible = false

//redraw your components

Object.Visible = true
```

I dont know if this is possible in your case but worth a try!

Comment: Thank you,can you explain more !

Comment: Whats the name of the component you are trying to redraw? In the code above Object stands for the component you are trying to redraw. Set it first to Visibel.false and then perform your redrawing and finally set Object to visible again.

Comment: not its not solving problem flicking still there ! what i done object.Visible = false;
         this.object.Invalidate();
         object.Visible = true; invalidate causes redraw

Comment: Have you tried SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() method? [MSDN link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx

Comment: what i found from debugging is Graphics.DrawLine() function taking lot of time when aero theme and very less when basic theme can any body guide how to improve

Comment: Haris, those won't do anything for owner-drawn controls. Drawing itself doesn't send any Layout events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use double buffer for you form object.

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

“works fine with Aero off” …sounds like a recourse issue to me…. Are you drawing in a paint event? If not where are you obtaining your graphics object from? You can programmatically disable desktop composition, I need it for some projects I do… but nothing related to drawing…

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref bool enabled);

const uint DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION = 0;
const uint DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION = 1;
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DwmEnableComposition")]
private static extern uint DwmEnableComposition(uint compositionAction);
```

usage:

```
 DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION);
```

Comment: just be sure to test if its Vista or Win7...XP will throw exception (API doesnt exist)

Comment: thank you, It works fine but some problems like notification coming and screen goes black for a second ,while window switches theme