# MVP Winform Solution/Project file Layout

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

Can someone help me define a physical file layout for a Winforms MVP multi-project solution?

There are many posts that touch on how to setup the views, interfaces, etc. ... the workings of MVP. I get that. Many posts also say that the physical layout of the project is very subjective and open to personal preference.

Well, I have no preference or experience or history. I am trying to simply build a "Template" solution for a current and for future MVP Winform projects. I am looking for some guidance on laying out the files of the solution, projects, folders, etc.

All of my MVP solutions will include the following:
- The solution itself with a master Winform
- A "modules" folder that contains projects for the various modules (ap, po, ar, inventory, etc.) for the solution
- A "helper" class library project that simply holds some of my methods, routines, etc. for performing common tasks
- A Business Logic class library project that contains all the BL
- A Data Access Logic class library project that handles all the data access routines - mostly using Entity Framework models

The main Winform will call User Controls from the respective Modules so everything is repeatable and portable. Where is the best place to keep the Interfaces, controllers if using Supervisor model or Passive model, etc.?

[image: Current solution file layout]

Comment: If you can, look into not using winforms in the future. Consider WPF, Silverlight or ASP.NET(I am assuming you want to stick with the .NET stack).

Comment: Yes - sticking with .NET for sure ... I'm most comfortable with Win and Web forms at this time so those are kind of a must.  Most of my coding is for internal apps that our users use on the network while connecting to Sql Server 2008.  There might be a few Webform spinoffs, but mostly Winforms.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that folders are for organizing and projects are for creating assemblies. Simplicity is a virtue. Consider carefully how many assemblies you would like to deploy with each release. I know you can IL merge, but if you don't have to why bother. If you do decide to create separate assemblies, I would organize by feature rather than structure.

Comment: Just thought it is easier to develop against a "module" and only deploy those .dlls instead of entire app.

Comment: Whether it is a "module" or not, from a code perspective you are using a namespace regardless of where the namespace is located (internal or external to your project).

Comment: In my outline for this solution, where would you recommend putting "base" items like user controls, base component controls, forms, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine.  One thing I want to caution you though, having gone down this road, is that it looks like you are going to have composite user controls that are made up of other user controls.

In WinForms, there is a massive problem with flicker in that scenario and you are going to have to do some tweaking so that the app does not appear sluggish.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286373/flickering-in-a-windows-forms-app) question to help you get around the issue.

Comment: Yes - composite user controls will be used.  Never thought about the flicker.

Comment: @BTI-Doug It was pretty bad, until I implemented the fix.  It's reasonable now.

Comment: 1 more follow-up I guess.  I've setup a simple mvp supervisor test with one m, v, and p.  I guess I should ask about the placement of supervisor controller and the actual views and presenters as they pertain to the module(s).

Comment: Your placement is fine.  I'd start coding now and not spend much more time on placement.