# Form backgroundimage flicker

Tags: c#, .net, image, background, flicker

Why setting a Form background (in the structure, before form loading), flickers when it is shown?

```
BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ProgramLaunchIntroScreen1200x800;
BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

When the application starts, first, at a very short time, the Form is seen without any background image then it is drawn on the screen! (I use the **double buffer** but still unsolved)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/112132/Flicker-free-Form-Painting). Anyone can explain what this override exactly does?

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
      get
      {
          CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;

          createParams.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;

          return createParams;
      }
}
```

Comment: [To reduce flicker by double buffer: SetStyle vs. overriding CreateParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872849/to-reduce-flicker-by-double-buffer-setstyle-vs-overriding-createparam)