# Display Error For WPF User Control Inside a Form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have an elementhost that does not render the WPF user control correctly when inside a custom TabControl or custom TableLayoutPanel.

I have commented out each of the overriden methods inside the custom controls and found the CreateParams method to be the problem, specifically in the line           cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;

I am not sure what the original reason for this line in the custom controls but was wondering if there was an extended window style value that is compatible with ElementHost.

```
    public class TableLayoutPanelWithBorders : TableLayoutPanel
    {
      protected override CreateParams CreateParams
      {
        get
        {
          CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
          cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
          return cp;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286373/flickering-in-a-windows-forms-app

Comment: Thanks Andy, ill see if i can get a solution from there.