# Form is shown before controls finish being painted

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

Various controls (mostly labels and panels) on my fairly simple c# WinForm form are not painted when the form is shown.  They finish being painted about a half second after the form is shown.

Is there an easy fix to this?

More details:

The panel that paint the slowest displays some data read from an SQL database.  The data is painted, by the text labels and background are not.  The panel holds a very small amount of data pulled from the database.

Another panel that finishes painting after the form appears only contains a few labels, one text control and one button.

Also, this form lays on top of another form whose only purpose is to cover the computer screen with a semi-transparent background.  When I delete this background form from the application the same controls still fail to finish painting before the form is shown (but now they finish being painted by only about a quarter second instead of by about a half second).

Comment: It sounds like there are one or more controls on the form that are slowing the painting down - what component(s) are shown on the troublesome panel?

Comment: @Will, one panel has a groupBox that contains three labels, one textbox, and one button. The other panel has a groupBox that contains a second panel that has six labels and a third panel, this third panel shows some data pulled from an SQL database (the data is just a few rows of user account names).

Comment: How does the SQL data get displayed on the third panel - is this panel owner-drawn, or does it contain e.g. a DataGridView?

Comment: The SQL data is written into several tabs of a TableLayoutPanel control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard Windows User32 rendering behavior.  The form and most of the controls are individual windows.  They each get a WM_PAINT message to tell them that they need to paint themselves, those messages are delivered one-by-one to each window, in Z-order.  When a control is slow to paint itself, that gets to be noticeable.  The unpainted rectangle of that control, and the ones after it, are visible for a brief moment.

Standard double-buffering techniques available in Windows Forms cannot solve this problem, you'd have to double-buffer the entire form.  That's possible, my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls) shows you how.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it (I need to test it a little more to be sure).  Once again, thanks for your great help.