# Drag and Drop Windows Forms Button

Tags: winforms

I create a new Windows Forms Application. I drag a button on to the form.
I need to drag and drop this button to another location within this form at run time. 
any code snippets or links are appreciated.

I spent half an hour searching before coming here.

Comment: How will you know when to "click" the button if you can also drag it?

Comment: I don't need click events. I just need the user to be able to re-arrange the controls shown on the form. No other functionality is needed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
  bool isDragged = false;
  Point ptOffset;
  private void button1_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     if ( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
     {
        isDragged = true;
        Point ptStartPosition = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        ptOffset = new Point();
        ptOffset.X = button1.Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;
        ptOffset.Y = button1.Location.Y - ptStartPosition.Y;
     }
     else
     {
        isDragged = false;
     }
  }

  private void button1_MouseMove( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     if ( isDragged )
     {
        Point newPoint = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);
        button1.Location = newPoint;
     }
  }

  private void button1_MouseUp( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
  {
     isDragged = false;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but the button still just sits there at its original location. I moved the code in MouseMove handler in MouseUp handler and now the button moves to new location. the new location is bit erratic. need to figure out that part. but thanks again for your help

Comment: The erratic location is probably due to the offset. You get mouse coordinates in a different format than the screen coordinates of the location. That's the reason for the calls to PointToScreen.

Comment: @msergeant Excellent example, works great! However I am experiencing a flickering tail when I drag the button around. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: I found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls :)