# Learning to drag and drop buttons in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I am currently trying to learn how to use Drag and Drop functionality in C# winforms. I've found some pretty neat tutorials and documentation online, but none that have helped steer me in the direction of a solution for my current problem.

To break my design goal down into just a simple example- I basically have a windows form that is split in half. There are regular ol' button controls on the left half, and nothing on the right. My goal is to be able to drag a button from the left side and drop it on the right. Doing so will grey out the button on the left side, and have the button now shown on the right. It doesn't have to show up wherever it was dropped on the right side- it can just appear in a preset location if necessary. I just want to be able to copy buttons from the left to right side.

Now, with that said- can anyone think of documentation, tutorials or anything else that might help steer me on the right track to figuring out how to do this? So far I've found that I'll need events for picking it up and putting it down, but beyond that I'm at something of a loss!

Normally I try to have more details in my questions, but since there is really nothing else to the program at this point I don't have much by way of code to show! So sorry for the somewhat vague question!

Thanks!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728870/drag-and-drop-windows-forms-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Walkthrough: Performing a Drag-and-Drop Operation in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0.aspx)

---

Edit: Changed link to english version

Answer (score 3):

Check out this drag-and-drop walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0.aspx [english]