# How to work with graphics correctly

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm trying to work with more advanced graphics besides the standard graphics.
One of my attempts was to create some useful control - a Knob.
I have an image contains 100 knobs with the values 1-100, and in the project i'm splitting it into a ***Bitmap array*** contains Bitmaps of each value (1-100).

This is how the knob looks like for some value, The value can be changed by holding the mouse down and dragging it up/down.

[image: Knob]

My technique is whenever the value changes, the BackgroundImage property of the Knob, which is a Control object, will be changed to the image located in the 'Value' index in the bitmaps array.  That means if I have bitmap array **X**, value **V** and the knob **K**, then`K.BackgroundImage = X[V]`. This action repeats for every value change.

**The Problem is that:** When I Increase/Decrease the value in run-time, the knob is like "flashing" during image changes. This leads me to think that my technique is not good, and I'd like to know if there is a better way to do that.

*The knob's design is not mine, just found over the internet.

Comment: How about some code (specifically the drawing code). What environment? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET?

Comment: Maybe there's a back-buffer setting somewhere in the control.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: You need to double buffer the animation. Are 100 sub images really needed? Pretty sure GDI+ can rotate images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# double buffering buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781402/c-sharp-double-buffering-buttons)

Comment: What happens if the user wants the knob to have 101 values?  (Or 1000?)  It will be tougher, but I'd recommend finding a way to draw your knob dynamically.  By the time you do, it's likely this issue will become a non-issue.

Comment: Oh by the way, it's a rotating knob, ie a circle. 100 frames is very strange. A circle based number would be better, 32, 64, 128 ect.

Comment: Hey sorry for that, i'm working with WinForms Application..

Comment: @AmirSidis Transforming images with GDI+ in c# http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0412192005054803AM/Transformations04.aspx

Comment: I don't think I can rotate it, it have to be longer when the value increases. Actually its 63 frames, I wrote the 100 just as an example..

Comment: @asawyer What do you mean when you say "double buffer"?

Comment: @AmirSidis http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4646/Flicker-free-drawing-using-GDI-and-C

Comment: @asawyer thank you, i'll check it, thank you all i'll read and ill try to solve it. :)

Comment: `How to work with graphics correctly` - Don't use winforms. It doesn't support that. Look at [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710117/updating-ui-in-c-sharp-using-timer/14711744#14711744)

Comment: Ah if you're looking to draw stuff in WinForm then read this mighty [FAQ](http://www.bobpowell.net/gdiplus_faq.htm) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go on the assumption that you've got a UserControl or some sort of Control derived subclass. If you don't, make it so...

While you're at it, read this terrific article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer

Bottom line, perform your painting in an `OnPaint` override and do the following in your constructor:

```
    SetStyle(
        ControlStyles.UserPaint |
        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
        ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

That should fix your flicker.