# Textbox flickering with timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix the flickering in User controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

my textbox flickers when it updates the text.
I update my textbox with a timer that ticks every 100 ms. (See it as a log window).

**Question**
How can I prevent this *flickering*?

Thanks!

Comment: No user can read 10 values/second. So lower the rate.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Even if I lower the rate to 500 ms, it still flickers.

Comment: You may just need a faster video card.

Comment: Never mind, got it! beta's solution worked, I added Application.DoEvents() EDIT: I think my video card is good enough: ATI 6870 crossfire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should either:

a) Slow down the tick rate of your timer

b) Enable double buffering

c) Put *Application.DoEvents()* right after the line which adds text to the TextBox

This is more of a workaround solution, though. I'd just lower the tickrate.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I've picked option c :).