# Flickering after resize despite the WS_EX_COMPOSIET flag and DoubleBuffered propertie

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flicker, aero

I have a TableLayoutPanel where I do some Drag&Drop stuff with the controls inside the layout. Unfortunately the controls are flickering after the drop action. I tried DoubleBuffered=true on all controls and a lot of other things. 
I also tried this solution: [How to fix the flickering in User controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls).
And actually it works pretty well with the mentioned CreateParams. But only until I resize the form.
It seems that windows forgets the WS_EX_COMPOSIET flag after a resize. 
It appears only with the aero theme. Without aero it keeps the settings of the CreateParams after a resize.

Is there any way to prevent flickering when the aero theme is turned on?

Comment: You can try to set `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag. See also: [Redraw issue on Windows10 with DoubleBuffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51824224/7713750)

Answer (score 1):

on the the form resize Events (onResizeBegin & on ResizeEnd) use the following code :

```
protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e) 
 {
    SuspendLayout();
    base.OnResizeBegin(e);
 }

protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e) 
 {
    ResumeLayout();
    base.OnResizeEnd(e);
 }
```

Comment: This was the first thing I did. Unfortunately without success. I got acceptable results with less nested controls.