# Screen flicker issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got an issue where some computers (rarely) start to flicker when using our application.  I found some odd code in the main form of our app:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {                
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;//composite window. Composite windows do not render/flickr when controls are born.  This speeds up loading.
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

The code appears to be sourced from an online [source](http://migrantfleet.net/how-to/how-to-avoid-flickering-windows-forms-controls) where they warn:

> You should be aware of the fact, though, that this only works in
>   environments where all control painting(within the hierarchy) is done
>   within WM_PAINT.  Applications using other/asynchronous means of
>   rendering into a control within the hierarchy will likely have theirs
>   problems with this solution causing unwanted behavior.

What exactly is WM_PAINT?  Do they mean all controls need to be painted via win32 API calls or is this what happens normally in a Load event?

There's a note saying the code was added to reduce a bug report regarding flicker...I just wonder if they threw the baby out with the bathwater on this one.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613272/719186).

Comment: WM_PAINT is the Win32 Paint message... Surfaced as Control.Paint in WinForms.

Comment: Using this in the constructor solved flickering in my case.:    SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
      ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DoubleBuffered = true;`