# how can i stop form flickering when using tabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Add()?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, tabcontrol, .net-4.5

am using below code to add a Form to a tabControls tabPage

```
private void btnStudents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (Form c in tabStudents.TabPages[0].Controls)
        {
            tabStudents.TabPages[0].Controls.Remove(c);
            c.Dispose();
        }

        //load form
        StudentsMasterForm f = new StudentsMasterForm
        {
            TopLevel = false,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        tabStudents.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(f);
        f.Show();
    }
```

the problem however is, there is too much form flickering when the button is clicked (i.e when the form is loaded). I have tried using  `tabCustomersAndOrders.TabPages[0].SuspendLayout();`
 and `tabCustomersAndOrders.TabPages[0].ResumeLayout();`

` but the flickering isn't going away.

I want to transition from one form to another to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: The answer to this question solved the issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpuse of marking this question as answered, here i post a link to another stackoverflow question that has a solution to my question.

Here is the link [how to fix the flickering in user controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Enabling double-buffering on the TabControl might help. With double-buffering, the control graphics all get rendered into memory, and then displayed only when all control rendering is complete.

This will mean a visible delay until completion, but should remove the flickering effect of multiple controls rendering.

The following will enable double-buffering:

```
myTabControl.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | 
      ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
      true);
```

The other alternative (the one I'd recommend) is to look at the problem from a different angle. Is there any way you can alter the UI design so that this kind of form population is pre-cached, or occurs before rendering to screen?

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this in your main GUI:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

this should solve your problem. At least from many things that I searched over the web, this one helped.