# Skinning Form in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application with registration Form.. I created a skin for that form 
and added panels with Labels and TextBoxes.

But when the form is loading it first doesn't look good and twitching..
and after some second it looks as it suppose to be  ...
I try to set the form property

> DoubleBuffered = true;
>    but it doesn't help..

I set the form backgroundImage to the image I want and 
in the form c'tor I have this code lines to set the form shape as the image:

> ```
>       this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
>         this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
> ```

this is what i see when the form is first loading
[image: when to form is loading]

now this is what I want to see when the form is first loading:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix the flickering in User controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

Comment: @HighCore hehe.. you're right! thanks anyway
and HansPassant thanks i'll look at the link you gave me