# How can I Stop Blinking my form on each click on Window form?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, panel

I have Main Panel of Form Size and placed many controls on it.my problem is

when I click(any where specially on scroll bar of main panel) on form it blinks each time which is looking odd.

so, could any body please tell me what's the reason behind this, or suggest me code to stop this. thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix the flickering in User controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a lot of control to a single form is not good,but for Stop Blinking in your form set property `DoubleBuffered` to `true`

**Edited**

make a custom panel and set DoubleBuffered to true:

```
public partial class CPanel : Panel
{
    public CPanel ()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        UpdateStyles();
    }
}
```

**HOW**
Insert new class to your project replace it code with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace yournamespace
{
    public partial class CPanel : Panel
    {
        public CPanel()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            UpdateStyles();
        }
    }
}
```

Build your `application`->go to your `form desig`n->now you have a new control in `toolbox`:Insert new control into your form ->copy your controls from old panel to new panel

Comment: Round about 50, but in my last application I had also added too many controls but it was working fine

Comment: Should I put the body of CPanel(above) method into my main panel body?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28159/discussion-between-saeed-khan-and-irsog)