# Panel background image flickering

Tags: c#, refresh, background-image, panel, flicker

I've a **Panel** which fills the parent Form.
And I used a **Timer** to capture screen ,
 
and set the screenshot as **background image** of Panel periodically.

However, it runs into crazy flickering. What can I do to solve it?

```
//Part of code
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DxScreenCapture sc = new DxScreenCapture();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            panelMain.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
         }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }



        void RefreshScreen()
        {
            Surface s = sc.CaptureScreen();

            DataStream ds = Surface.ToStream(s, ImageFileFormat.Bmp);
            panelMain.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ds);

            s.Dispose();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshScreen();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a double buffered panel. Inherit panel, set DoubleBuffered to true and use that panel instead of default panel:

```
    namespace XXX
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A panel which redraws its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker.
        /// </summary>
        public class PanelDoubleBuffered : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        {
            public PanelDoubleBuffered()
                : base()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Additionally I want to encourage you to take care a little more about the resources you use. Whenever an object implements the IDisposable interface - dispose the object when not needed any more. This is very important when dealing with unmanaged resources, such as streams!

```
    void RefreshScreen()
    {
            using (Surface s = sc.CaptureScreen())
            {
                using (DataStream ds = Surface.ToStream(s, ImageFileFormat.Bmp))
                {
                    Image oldBgImage = panelMain.BackgroundImage;
                    panelMain.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ds);
                    if (oldBgImage != null)
                        oldBgImage.Dispose();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Good! It works. I also found [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21874673/2080233) which works. And thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer by myself from other site. It sets some **ControlStyles** on the panel like the following code. And no flickering any more.

```
class SomePanel : Panel
{
    public SomePanel()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually an easier solution in Visual Studio that requires no code!

If you go to **Solution Explorer** and then double click on your form (**Form1**) there will be a list that pops up (If it does not pop up you just have to right click on your form and go to **Properties** and double click again). Then, go to **DoubleBuffered** and change it to **True**.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me , Try this

```
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams handleParms = base.CreateParams;
                handleParms.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
                return handleParms;
            }
        }
```