# WinForms control flickers when changing size

Tags: winforms, telerik, flicker

Generally, its about Telerik RadDesktopAlert
and its control named Popup.

So when i set size to new value:

```
_textBox.Clear();
        _textBox.Text = txtMessage;

        _textBox.Visible = 
        _btnCollapse.Enabled = 
        _btnNotify.Enabled =
        _panelWithButtons.Visible = true;

        AlertControl.FixedSize = new Size(ALERT_WIDTH, _height);
        AlertControl.Popup.Size = AlertControl.FixedSize;
```

I tried to run then

```
AlertControl.Popup.Invalidate();
```

But it still flickers.
I tried to set DoubleBuffered via reflection, but this doesnt help.

In other words, how to remove flickering when i set size for the control ?

PS As you understand, i cannot inherit from that popup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls

Comment: i dont have any form, i cant override 3rd party control and cant inherit

Comment: Are you just throwing out terms? I think when resizing controls in WinForms you are going to get some flicker as they redraw themselves; It's just the nature of the beast. You can attempt to optimize out the effect of the best you can, or you can use WPF. For what it's worth, I tried part of your code and there was no noticeable or prolonged flickering despite constant resizing of the DesktopAlert.