# CreateParams and XP

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp, createparams

I have searched it on internet and on stackoverflow as well but i haven't got any correct/reliable solution.

I want to remove flickering from one of my c# Windows Form.

So I have overriden CreateParams method in following manner

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

This removes flicker from my Application when used in Vista, Windows 7 and 8. But in XP my controls are randomly changed. My checkboxes becomes invisible.

I have referred the stack over flow question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls). But i cannnot use it as I dont have any MaximizeBox. This is happening in a used defined control !
Please suggest me a feasible solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix the flickering in User controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

Comment: I'm not aware of an XP specific failure mode.  Just punt the problem, XP users have low expectations anyway.  Only set the flag if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6).  Attribution is required here btw.