# C# launch form when images fully loaded

Tags: c#, image, forms, launch

I'm making C# application design with images, but when I launch it, I see loading images (~1sec), so how to make simple loader, when images (background, logo, etc..) fully loads, to show my app? I know it's possible but I don't know how to. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like standard behaviour. The controls get painted one by one in z-order and if one is slow the rest may appear to flicker.

You could try double buffering the whole form as shown here: 
[How to fix the flickering in User controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)

Alternatively you could suspend the layout while everything is drawn and resume it afterwards:
[How do I suspend painting for a control and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children)