# form slow loading when go to another form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My application has several tabs (sections) and user is going to move between them .
but them problem is that when I move between them, it appears slowly and part by part. actually it's not smooth.

for example in Reports tab , I have 2 forms that one of them is behind the another one, and when I click *Report* tab , the second one that is behind, loads for a moment. (that should not load at first)

before selecting the report tab :
[image]

report form selected and you can see the way of loading:
[image]

after a secound that loading completed :
[image]

and this is the form that is behind, I show it for you to see it . (by pressing a button in toolbar)
[image]

or for example in this picture, I'm going to change my tab to *Graph*
[image]

what is the best way to prevent this problem?
I use WinForms C# .Net 4

Comment: Is "viberations" another word for flicker?  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613272/17034).

Comment: it's just low speed loading actually

Comment: @HansPassant that topic solved my problem :)