# How to restrict flickering issue while resize the custom form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have derived a class from System.Windows.Forms.Form class to create a custom form.
I have created my own customization by override wndproc.
This issue,i have added the control and dock fill the control.
I had two problem with this

1. While I resize the form,the background of the form appears that is
   the control paints after I have resize the form.
2. While I maximize the form,the same problem occurs.

I have no idea how to fix.Please give me any concern about it.

Comment: It does indeed repaint the control. Try setting `this.DoubleBuffered = true` in the constructor of your derived form. Let me know if it removes the flickering

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls/2613272#2613272

Comment: Yeldar thanks for your reply sorry it still reproduces the same.