# C# Panel Fade in and Fade Out glitches

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

```
 while (panel6.Left != 0) //0 is the end postion and it'll start at -600
 {
     panel6.Left += 10;
     Thread.Sleep(50);
 }
```

This is the code I use to fade in  a panel and to fade in works perfectly
https://i.vgy.me/QE5M15.gif

this is the glitch I mean when fading out it like idk how to explain it

I've tried using a costum panel code from S.O. but that didn't work either, I also tried changing the alpha in a loop but that also glitches

I tried adding

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

that didn't work either

Also tried

```
async void Move()
{
    while (panel7.Left != -600) //0 is the end postion and it'll start at -600
    {
        panel7.Left -= 10;
        Task.Delay(5);
    }
}
```

but now the panel just disappears and doesn't do the slide effect

Comment: You have a background image, part of some control. The control that holds the Image should have these styles set: `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer`. `Thread.Sleep()` is not a good idea. An `async` proc with `Task.Delay()` will work better here.

Comment: It is remarkable that it doesn't glitch worse than that.  You can't hang the UI thread in a loop like that and expect parts of the window to still paint correctly.  Are you doing this in a worker thread?  Uh-oh.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls

Comment: @Hans Passant IIRC, that method loses its *effect* if the Form is minimized/maximized. Do you know how to make it stick (without recreating the handle, that is)?

Comment: @Jimi check edit

Comment: @HansPassant Check edit

Comment: Where did you put those lines of code? `while (panel7.Left != -600) panel7.Left -= 10;`? Are you sending the Panel off-screen? Starting from where? How are you calling the async method? From where? Post the complete code.

Comment: @Jimi https://pastebin.com/raw/mVLVJw57 The panel starts off screen (-600) and I'm 1 trying to make panel slide in which works fine, and 2 make the panel slide off which doesn't work

Comment: Using the same settings that I proposed: [Sliding Panel](https://imgur.com/a/CHMtxLx).

Answer (score 0):

Try these modifications:

- All elements are animated using the async/await patter; `Task.Run()` for the gradient color
- The sliding Panel works like in the example I posted.
- All procedures are non-blocking, so the animations work when the Form is faded in and out or moved around

Set the Form's `AutoScaleMode` to **`AutoScaleMode.Dpi`** and possibly [make your application DPIAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), if you haven't already.

```
public partial class Main_Menu3 : Form
{
    bool Active;
    //Color setcolor = new Color();
    Color StartColor = Color.FromArgb(91, 65, 193);
    Color EndColor = Color.FromArgb(242, 90, 95);
    int Steps = 30;

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    public Main_Menu3()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
                      ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
                      ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Color> GetGradients(Color start, Color end, int steps)
    {
        int stepA = ((end.A - start.A) / (steps - 1));
        int stepR = ((end.R - start.R) / (steps - 1));
        int stepG = ((end.G - start.G) / (steps - 1));
        int stepB = ((end.B - start.B) / (steps - 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            yield return Color.FromArgb(start.A + (stepA * i),
                                        start.R + (stepR * i),
                                        start.G + (stepG * i),
                                        start.B + (stepB * i));
        }
    }

    private async Task SetGradients()
    {
        IEnumerable<Color> colors = GetGradients(StartColor, EndColor, Steps);

        while (true) {
            foreach (var color in colors) {
                if (color == colors.Last()) {
                    colors = colors.Reverse();
                    break;
                }
                await Task.Delay(1);
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { label6.ForeColor = color; }));
            }
        }
    }

    private void CustomButton1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customButton1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    private void CustomButton1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customButton1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);
    }

    private void Main_Menu3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists("C://RC-M_Theme")) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C://RC-M_Theme");
        }
        if (File.Exists("C://RC-M_Theme/backgroundimage.png")) {
            this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("C:/RC-M_Theme/backgroundimage.png");
        }
    }

    private void Main_Menu3_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        => Task.Run(async ()=> await SetGradients());

    private async void Main_Menu3_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Active = true;
        base.Opacity = 0.75;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
            bool active = this.Active;
            if (active) {
                base.Opacity += 0.01;
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void Main_Menu3_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            this.Active = false;
            base.Opacity = 0.75;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
                bool flag = !this.Active;
                if (flag) {
                    base.Opacity -= 0.01;
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void Panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    private void Main_Menu3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    private async void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ShowPanel(panel7, 50);
    }

    private async void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await HidePanel(panel7, 50);
    }

    int scrollStep = 20;
    bool isPanelShowing = false;

    private async Task ShowPanel(Panel panel, int delay)
    {
        if (isPanelShowing) return;
        isPanelShowing = true;
        while (panel.Left < 0) {
            panel.Left += scrollStep;
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
        isPanelShowing = false;
    }

    private async Task HidePanel(Panel panel, int delay)
    {
        if (isPanelShowing) return;
        isPanelShowing = true;
        while (panel.Left > -panel.Width) {
            panel.Left -= scrollStep;
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
        isPanelShowing = false;
    }

    private async void FadeIn(Control ctrl, int interval = 80)
    {
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 39, 42, 52);
        while (ctrl.BackColor.A < 245) {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(ctrl.BackColor.A + 10, 39, 42, 52);
        }
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 39, 42, 52);
    }

    private async void FadeOut(Form form, int interval = 80)
    {
        Color c = form.BackColor;
        //Object is fully visible. Fade it out
        while (form.Opacity > 0.1f) {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
            form.Opacity -= 0.05f;
        }
        form.Opacity = 0.1f; //make fully invisible       
    }
}
```