# Control flickers while its location is continuously changed

Tags: vb.net, timer, user-controls, location, controls

I have a button inside a form. The button moves horizontally from one point to another by continuously varying the Button.Location.X from 0 to 1000 using a timer. See code below.

```
Timer1.Interval = 100
Dim i as Integer = -1
Private Sub Timer1_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Button1.Location = New Point(i, 50)
If i = 1000
i = 0
End If
i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Now the problem is while the button is moving it flickers. How do I stop the flickering?
Tried using Hans Passant's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612487/8247997) question but it's not working.

Comment: Try to set Form's property **DoubleBuffered** to `True`

Comment: @evry1falls tried it. Not working.

Comment: Does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613272/13393566) ?

Comment: @evry1falls not working.

Comment: Instead of a Button, you can draw an Image/Shape on a PictureBox (or a Flat Label), using a Timer set to 55-75 and increments of `.5f` (so use a Single type). Adjust as needed to increment the speed. Set `InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low` and `SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed`. The Form's DoubleBuffer is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jimi after trying your solution the flickering has reduced a little bit but still noticeable.

Comment: @Jimi In the button's paint event handler I set: `e.graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low` and `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed`

Comment: Read again my comment. I wrote something completely different.

Comment: @Jimi But I wanted a button. Does your solution only work for picture boxes??

Comment: That doesn't *work with PictureBoxes*, it work better because you're drawing on a buffered context using floating point values. Your Button doesn't *flicker*, it *stutters*, since the movement is performed inside a fixed grid. With that *speed*, a human eye can easily detect the difference in position. Drawing a graphics object and using floating point values to define its position (plus subtle anti-alias to *fade* the borders), the movement is more difficult to detect, so it appears more *fluid*.

Comment: Don't set the `Location` if you're only varying one aspect. Set `Top` to move vertically and `Left` to move horizontally. ALWAYS read the documentation so you know what members are available.